# validate my form and header to another success page

Tags: php, validation

I am trying to validate my form fields and redirect the user to success page

so this is the PHP code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


$experiences = $courses = $careerObjective = $availability = $typeOfJob = $rank = $jTitle = $otherJobTitle
    = $salaryRange = $currency = $workIn = "";

$experiencesErr = $coursesErr = $careerObjectiveErr = $availabilityErr = $typeOfJobErr = $rankErr = $jTitleErr
    = $otherJobTitleErr = $salaryRangeErr = $currencyErr = $workInErr = "";


$id = "";
$uid = "";

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    $error = array(
        "coursesErr"=>"",
        "careerObjectiveErr"=>"",
        "otherJobTitleErr"=>"",
        "experiencesErr"=>"",
        "availabilityErr"=>"",
        "typeOfJobErr"=>"",
        "rankErr"=>"",
        "jTitleErr"=>"",
        "salaryRangeErr"=>"",
        "currencyErr"=>"",
    );

    if (empty($_POST['experiences'])) {
        $error['experiencesErr'] = "Experiences Required";
    } else {
        $experiences = check_input($_POST['experiences']);
        if (!preg_match("/^[0-9_a-zA-Z ]*$/", $experiences)) {
            $error['experiencesErr'] = "Only letters, numbers and '_' allowed";
        }
    }

    $courses = check_input($_POST['courses']);
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9_a-zA-Z ]*$/", $courses)) {
        $error['coursesErr'] = "Only letters, numbers and '_' allowed";
    }

    $careerObjective = check_input($_POST['careerObjective']);
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9_a-zA-Z ]*$/", $careerObjective)) {
        $error['careerObjectiveErr'] = "Only letters, numbers and '_' allowed";
    }

    if (empty($_POST['availability'])) {
        $error['availabilityErr'] = "Availability Required";
    } else {
        $availability = check_input($_POST['availability']);
    }

    if (empty($_POST['typeOfJob'])) {
        $error['typeOfJobErr'] = "Full/Part Time Required";
    } else {
        $typeOfJob = check_input($_POST['typeOfJob']);
    }

    if (empty($_POST['typeOfJob'])) {
        $error['typeOfJobErr'] = "Full/Part Time Required";
    } else {
        $typeOfJob = check_input($_POST['typeOfJob']);
    }

    if (empty($_POST['rank'])) {
        $error['rankErr'] = "Self-assessment Required";
    } else {
        $rank = check_input($_POST['rank']);
    }

    if (empty($_POST['jTitle'])) {
        $error['jTitleErr'] = "Job Field Required";
    } else {
        $jTitle = check_input($_POST['jTitle']);
    }

    $otherJobTitle = check_input($_POST['otherJobTitle']);
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9_a-zA-Z ]*$/", $otherJobTitle)) {
        $error['otherJobTitleErr'] = "Only letters, numbers and '_' allowed";
    }

    if (empty($_POST['salaryRange'])) {
        $error['salaryRangeErr'] = "Salary Range Required";
    } else {
        $salaryRange = check_input($_POST['salaryRange']);
    }

    if (empty($_POST['currency'])) {
        $error['currencyErr'] = "Currency Required";
    } else {
        $currency = check_input($_POST['currency']);
    }

    $workIn = check_input($_POST['workIn']);

    if(!$error){
        $putData = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO hired_ts_info (id, uid, experiences, courses, career_objective,
        availability, type_of_job, rank, job_title, other_job_title, salary_range, currency, workIn)
        VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

        $putData->bind_param('iisssssssssss', $id, $uid, $experiences, $courses, $careerObjective, $availability,
        $typeOfJob, $rank, $jTitle, $otherJobTitle, $salaryRange, $currency, $workIn);

        if($putData->execute()){
            header("Location:?pid=4&pp=2&pps=technicalSummary&m=g");
        }else{
            echo "Error on executing";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

and this is the first lines of the HTML code

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" id="personRegestrationPage4">


<div class="f_left width100percent">
    <div class="TwoLine">
        <label for="experiences" class="requiredFields">experiences and qualifications</label>
        <textarea name="experiences" id="experiences"></textarea>
        <span class="notAllowed"><?php if (isset($error)) {
                echo $error['experiencesErr'];
            }?></span>
    </div>

    <div class="TwoLine">
        <label for="courses">Previous Courses</label>
        <textarea name="courses" id="courses"></textarea>
        <span class="notAllowed"><?php if (isset($error)) {
                echo $error['coursesErr'];
            } ?></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the submit button code

```
<input type="submit" name="subTs" id="subTs" value="Save Changes" class="submitBtn4">
```

**Problem**
now when I submit the form it come back without inserting anything to the db and no error message received

**Update**

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


$experiences = $courses = $careerObjective = $availability = $typeOfJob = $rank = $jTitle = $otherJobTitle
    = $salaryRange = $currency = $workIn = "";

$experiencesErr = $coursesErr = $careerObjectiveErr = $availabilityErr = $typeOfJobErr = $rankErr = $jTitleErr
    = $otherJobTitleErr = $salaryRangeErr = $currencyErr = $workInErr = "";


$id = "";
$uid = "";

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    $error = array();

    if (empty($_POST['experiences'])) {
        $error['experiencesErr'] = "Experiences Required";
    } else {
        $experiences = check_input($_POST['experiences']);
        if (!preg_match("/^[0-9_a-zA-Z ]*$/", $experiences)) {
            $error['experiencesErr'] = "Only letters, numbers and '_' allowed";
        }
    }

    $courses = check_input($_POST['courses']);
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9_a-zA-Z ]*$/", $courses)) {
        $error['coursesErr'] = "Only letters, numbers and '_' allowed";
    }

    $careerObjective = check_input($_POST['careerObjective']);
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9_a-zA-Z ]*$/", $careerObjective)) {
        $error['careerObjectiveErr'] = "Only letters, numbers and '_' allowed";
    }

    if (empty($_POST['availability'])) {
        $error['availabilityErr'] = "Availability Required";
    } else {
        $availability = check_input($_POST['availability']);
    }

    if (empty($_POST['typeOfJob'])) {
        $error['typeOfJobErr'] = "Full/Part Time Required";
    } else {
        $typeOfJob = check_input($_POST['typeOfJob']);
    }

    if (empty($_POST['typeOfJob'])) {
        $error['typeOfJobErr'] = "Full/Part Time Required";
    } else {
        $typeOfJob = check_input($_POST['typeOfJob']);
    }

    if (empty($_POST['rank'])) {
        $error['rankErr'] = "Self-assessment Required";
    } else {
        $rank = check_input($_POST['rank']);
    }

    if (empty($_POST['jTitle'])) {
        $error['jTitleErr'] = "Job Field Required";
    } else {
        $jTitle = check_input($_POST['jTitle']);
    }

    $otherJobTitle = check_input($_POST['otherJobTitle']);
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9_a-zA-Z ]*$/", $otherJobTitle)) {
        $error['otherJobTitleErr'] = "Only letters, numbers and '_' allowed";
    }

    if (empty($_POST['salaryRange'])) {
        $error['salaryRangeErr'] = "Salary Range Required";
    } else {
        $salaryRange = check_input($_POST['salaryRange']);
    }

    if (empty($_POST['currency'])) {
        $error['currencyErr'] = "Currency Required";
    } else {
        $currency = check_input($_POST['currency']);
    }

    $workIn = check_input($_POST['workIn']);

    if (!$error) {
        $putData = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO hired_ts_info (id, uid, experiences, courses, career_objective,
        availability, type_of_job, rank, job_title, other_job_title, salary_range, currency, workIn)
        VALUE(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

        $putData->bind_param('iisssssssssss', $id, $uid, $experiences, $courses, $careerObjective, $availability,
            $typeOfJob, $rank, $jTitle, $otherJobTitle, $salaryRange, $currency, $workIn);

        if ($putData->execute()) {
            header("Location:?pid=4&pp=2&pps=technicalSummary&m=g");
        } else {
            echo "Error on executing";
        }
    } else {
        $error = array(
            "coursesErr" => "",
            "careerObjectiveErr" => "",
            "otherJobTitleErr" => "",
            "experiencesErr" => "",
            "availabilityErr" => "",
            "typeOfJobErr" => "",
            "rankErr" => "",
            "jTitleErr" => "",
            "salaryRangeErr" => "",
            "currencyErr" => "",
        );
    }
}
?>
```

still that didn't solve the issue
1- now the code submit correctly and gos to my DB.
2- if the fields is empty or not allowed input the message don't appear any more under the fields
any Ideas pleasee

Comment: Is your action working, so is the script executing? I mean you miss a "echo" before $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']..I'm not sure if it's necessary..

Comment: try printing out the $error before running query.

Comment: @MarcelBalzer luckily `action=""` and `action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"` and `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"` obtain same output (:

Comment: `$error` is always true. You initialize it at the beginning. So, you don't go in the if statement and reload the page.

Comment: @Marcel Balzer I try this too but no luck put `echo` before the `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`

Comment: @Debflav sorry I didn't get this correctly what do you suggest me to do

Comment: @YousefAltafWasti: One of possible solution is to initialize your array as `$error = array();`.

Comment: do I have to `unset` the `$error` What I can do with it?

Comment: @Debflav but it's already `$error = array();`

Comment: `$error = array( "coursesErr"=>"", [...])` is your problem. It's never false. For debugging you can add an `else` after your `if( !$error)` and print your array.

Comment: @Debflav but now the error message do not appear any more under the fields if the fields is empty or not allowed input detected but it solved the first problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59507/discussion-between-yousef-altaf-and-debflav).

Comment: @YousefAltaf : I can't access to chat due to proxy. Anyway, you should remove the array in the `else` statement. I just wanted to `print_r($error)` and see what's it contains. Your code should works like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind your script is not showing any error is this

that you set the value again for your error in the else statement which is empty; in these line

```
else {
        $error = array(
            "coursesErr" => "",
            "careerObjectiveErr" => "",
            "otherJobTitleErr" => "",
            "experiencesErr" => "",
            "availabilityErr" => "",
            "typeOfJobErr" => "",
            "rankErr" => "",
            "jTitleErr" => "",
            "salaryRangeErr" => "",
            "currencyErr" => "",
        );
    }
```

in these line you set the value for your $error Arrray, and set them to empty.
The things is this even you set the array value before, but when the php reaches these line, it changes those value to empty value which you define,

For example if you have a code like this

```
$x=4; 
$x=5;
```

even though you got same variable, but if you `echo $x;` its gonna give you always 5 cause this is the last value for $x;

to understand it more clearly what you should do  give some value in any $error array in else statement it will show that $error

like this

```
$error = array(
            "coursesErr" => "my name is spider man",
            "careerObjectiveErr" => "",
            "otherJobTitleErr" => "",
            "experiencesErr" => "",
            "availabilityErr" => "",
            "typeOfJobErr" => "",
            "rankErr" => "",
            "jTitleErr" => "",
            "salaryRangeErr" => "",
            "currencyErr" => "",
        );
    }
```

and than run the code, it will show you that particular error not any other, because you set it value,

so what should you do now, easy option is this remove the else statement completely,

Comment: sorry I removed the `array` completely in this case everything gos right but it also do not allow the error messages to display under every fields that has been empty or not allowed input

Comment: my `PHP` code is before the `HTML` and about the messages it should appear under every field telling that this field is required or this is not allowed input ... on anther hand the process is going fine ... if the everything is OK in the fields it redirect to the success page and insert in the `db` and if there is any empty fields it stops but not showing the required under the fields ... is it clear now @Arif_suhail_123